# Возврат текста в C

Tags: c

Есть такая проблема. Нужно перевести число в 16ричную систему счисления. Замену чисел 10-16 на буквы сделал в подпрограмме через switch. Но после выполнения вместо нужной буквы программа возвращает код буквы из ASCI.

Как сделать, чтобы возвращало именно букву?

```
int iftool(char t)
{
    switch (t) {
    case 0:
        return t = 0;
        break;
    // 
    // ...
    // 
    case 9:
        return t = 9;
        break;
    case 10:
        return t = 'A';
        break;
    case 11:
        return 'B';
        break;
    case 12:
        return t = ('C');
        break;
    case 13:
        return t = ('D');
        break;
    case 14:
        return t = ('E');
        break;
    case 15:
        return t = ('F');
        break;
    }
}
```

часть которая переводит из 2й в 16 систему.

```
l=0;
r=1;
m=1;
n=0;
while (l<=k)
{
    n=(n+(number[l]*r));
    if ( m%4==0 || l==k)
    {
        r=1;
        m=1;
        t=n;
        t=iftool(t);
        mas[x]=t;
        n=0;
        printf ("lol-%d",mas[x]);
        x++;
    }
    else
    {
        m++;
        r=r*2;
    }
    l++;
}
```

Comment: у тебя функция возвращает какой тип ? и какой надо 

Comment: то еть для char хоть литерал, хоть код одно и тоже , он приводится к инту все равно, но вот возвращаешь ты инт, значит код хранится в t, а при выводе желательно тогда (char)t делать, либ тогда сделай сразу 
char iftool(char)

Comment: исправил теперь char iftool (char t) но проблема не ушла

Comment: В Вашем коде есть ошибка(и). Вы пишите return t = 0; ... t = 9; ... t = 'A'; - в итоге получается, что для значений от 0 до 9 вы возвращаете не код нужного символа, а само значение. Вы бы должны написать return t = '0'; ... t = '9'; ... - тогда функция будет возвращать нужный Вам символ... Но все-таки switch - слишком громоздкое и неэффективное решение. Даже if/else ( if(t <= 9) return t+'0'; else return t-10+'A'; - без проверки на валидность, естественно) выглядят эффективнее... Хотя, может быть, современные оптимизирующие компиляторы и сгенерируют хороший код...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

привести к типу char

Comment: а лучше кусочек этого кода, не знаю как другие, но я лично не телепат)

Comment: да и вообще в сях вывод в шестнадцатиричку решается одной строкой: 
printf("%x",15);
думаю резалт ясен!

Comment: если бы все так просто. в программе обязательно использовать подпрограмму. 

как подпрограмму я решил использовать свич для смены значения

Comment: сделай грязный хак))типа

void iftool(int i){printf("%x",i);}

Comment: а можн вопрос, задача состоит в том, чтобы вывести введенное число в 16 системе??

Comment: задача состоит в том. чтобы любое десятичное число сначала перевести в 2ю систему а затем в 8ю и 16ю системы.

Comment: printf ("lol-%с",mas[x]);

Comment: спасибо большое. теперь все ок

Answer (score 4):

Frank, я бы Вам посоветовал использовать вместо switch простой массив:

char x16trans[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};

и далее (в a - число от 0 до 15):

`char x16(int a)
{
return x16trans[a];
}`

Answer (score 0):

исходник:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
       int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
       string b[] = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
string str = "";
int x1,x2;
cin >> x1;
int z[8];
for (int i = 0; i < 8;i++)
{
    x2 = x1/16;
    z[i] = x1 - (x2*16);
    // cout << "x: " << x2 << "\t"<< "z: " << z[i]<
    x1 = x2;
}
for (int j = 8, j2 = 0; j > 0; j--,j2++)    
{
    for(int n = 0; n < 16; n++)
         if (z[j] == a[n])
         {
               str = str + b[n];
         }
 }
 cout << str;
 cin.get();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: решение уже нашли , но все равно спасибо

Comment: Вы немного ошиблись... По-видимому массив b должен выглядеть вот так: string b[] = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"};